# ¿Cuál es el origen/explicación de la expresión "Tomarse algo a pecho"?

Tags: expresiones, historia, cuerpo-humano

Yo he escuchado la expresión *tomarse algo a pecho* en el sentido de ofenderse por algo o tomarse algo personalmente. Tiene una entrada en el DLE e incluso algunas variaciones que no conocía. ¿Por qué *tomarse algo a pecho* se relaciona con ofenderse en exceso por algo?

> [**tomar**, o **tomarse**, alguien **a pecho**, o **a pechos**, algo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=SGn4UWw%7CSGnBUDZ%7CSGoYqxA)
>
> 1. *locs. verbs.* Mostrar mucho interés y empeño.
> 2. *locs. verbs.* Ofenderse excesivamente por ello.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El origen de la expresión *tomarse algo a pecho* es antiguo, y viene dado por los significados metafóricos de *pecho*. Según el *Autoridades* (1737), entre dichos significados ya estaban los de "el interior del hombre" (moralmente hablando), y también "valor, esfuerzo, fortaleza y constancia".

Si nos vamos más atrás, el *Covarrubias* (1611) nos dice:

> El hombre tiene el pecho estendido mas que ningun otro animal, y los que le tienen angosto son de poco animo, y de pocas cosas se congoxan, y de alli nacen las maneras de hablar. Hombre de pecho, el valeroso. Hombre de poco pecho, el timido. [...] Tomar â pechos una cosa, procurarla con veras. Buen pecho, bien intencionado. Mal pecho, mal intencionado.

De hecho se dice *pecho* a "cierto tributo que se da al Rey", y *pechar* el que paga dicho tributo. Pero esto es otra historia. Volviendo al tema, si tienes buen pecho es que aúnas valor, esfuerzo y demás, de donde se saca el primer significado de "tomarse algo a pecho" como "mostrar mucho interes y empeño".

Resulta curioso el matiz que introdujeron en la definición de 1803 como "tomar alguna cosa con demasiada eficacia y empeño". Más adelante se añadió el matiz de "hacer de algo un gran asunto". Y solo en ediciones muy recientes se añade el sentido de ofenderse por algo. Posiblemente se añadiera como consecuencia del uso de la frase tras decirle a alguien que no es capaz de hacer algo y este ponerse a hacerlo como si no hubiera un mañana: se ha tomado a pecho algo como consecuencia de haberse ofendido por las palabras de desánimo de otro.

Los primeros usos escritos de la expresión datan de principios del siglo XVI, como este:

> *Y con todo esto fue, Señor, tanta tu nobleza, que quasi te olvidaste de los peligros y no veniste como rogado a nos socorrer, sino rogándonos que consintamos ser de ti socorridos, tomando la cosa tan a pechos y tan por tuyo nuestro negocio como si todo tu estado te fuera en ello.*
>
> Francisco de Osuna, "Primera parte del Abecedario espiritual", 1528 (España).

Answer (score 1):

Creo que se usa *pecho* aquí como una metáfora para *corazón*, como en el inglés "to take to heart" o el francés "prendre à cœur", que llevan los mismos significados.